# Does quasi-increasing implies almost everywhere continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a function such that for every $x_0\in [0,1]$, we have $\limsup_{a\to x_0^-}f(a)\le f(x_0)\le \liminf_{b\to x_0^+}f(b)$. Do we have $f$ is continuous almost everywhere in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: In fact, equality holds throughout for all but countably many $x_0 \in [0,1].$ See [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/231462/15780).

Comment: Dear @DaveL.Renfro, thank you very much for your answer ! It is helpful.